# Convert virtual field to "physical" field?

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, virtual-field

I created a virtual field "`attr`" for a vector layer in QGIS using a expression for the values. These values will be updated as data changes.

How can I convert/materialize this virtual field to a normal "physical" field that gets calculated once and for all?

The perfect solution would be one that is not "delete the virtual field, then add a new, normal field using the same name and expression".

Answer (score 0):

You can export the layer to a new one, it will convert the virtual fields to real ones.

Comment: I want to change the original source, copying e.g. a multi Gigabyte vector table is no option in this case.